# Android Development - Designing User Interface for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android-layout, android

I am working on a private android application that will involve the use of a variety of graphical images. Each activity in the application will have a picture sequence. The application will be developed for android tablets.

My question is how do I go about making the images adjustable for variable screen sizes ? Would I just need to have all the parameters as density pixels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use the different folder types found in [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), for 10inch screens you would use for example `layout-sw720dp`, the same would go for the drawable folders where your images would go, use the `drawable-xhdpi`

Comment: Really ? Is there another way to do it ? I thought density pixels were meant to be used so that size of images changes with the screen size. So wouldn't that be enough ? What about adding supports-screens android:resizeable="true" in the manifest, would that work ?

Comment: I have only used the different folders; yes that is what the density means the OS will choose the image in the drawable folders based on the screen density, is that not what you want? to base it on screen size use `drawable-sw720dp`

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I misunderstood you in the beginning. I understand that density pixels would solve my problem. Thanks for your help!